# default value in struts2 list box

Tags: jsp, listbox, struts2, struts, jsp-tags

we have list box.This will show the different states in US. I want state "LA" should be as preselected.But I dont know the position of "LA" in the list. It may vary.We are using the following script for this.

```
<select id="state" name="state" title="State" class="js_required prompt_text grid_2" tabindex="5">
                <option>State</option>
                <s:iterator value="@com.homeservices.action.utils.StateCode@values()">
                    <option value="<s:property/>"><s:property/></option>
                </s:iterator>
</select>
```

var @com.homeservices.action.utils.StateCode@values() gives a list of values:

```
AA
AE
AK
CA
CT
IL
LA
MA
MD
```

......etc.

Can some one please suggest how to make LA as a preselected state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Struts Approach

```
<s:select id="state"
          name="state"
          title="State"
          headerKey=""
          headerValue="State"
          list="@action.StateCode@values()"
          cssClass="js_required prompt_text grid_2"
          value="@action.StateCode@LA"
          tabindex="5"/>
```

### The JSP Approach (JSTL/JSP-EL)

```
<%@ page import="action.StateCode" %>
<c:set var="states" value="<%=StateCode.values()%>"/>

<select id="state" name="state" title="State"
        class="js_required prompt_text grid_2" tabindex="5">
    <option>State</option>
    <c:forEach items="${states}" var="state">
        <option value="${state}" ${state == 'LA' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${state}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this script just before `</html>` and after fill-up with `state`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("state").value = "LA";
</script>
```

Comment: Look more like a workaround than a real solution. It would really surprise me if this is really not possible with Struts2. All other MVC frameworks I know definitely supports this.

Comment: yes if we put this at end of the web page this will execute. As he want to select LA which is not index. either he might be go with `<option selected value='LA'` in code for example. :)